# Use AJAX on a form with multiple buttons

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have a form that has two text areas and three buttons, "Copy", "Reverse" and "Clear". I would like the buttons to, respectively, copy the text from one text area to the other, take the text from the first area and place the reverse of it in the other, and clear both text areas using AJAX.

I know how to do these functions in PHP but I can't seem to get the AJAX to work at all. Here is my existing code, any help  would be appreciated:

```
<?php

    function produce_form() {
    $form['input'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#title' => t('Input text'),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="in-text">',
        '#value' => '',
        '#attributes' => array(
            'placeholder' => t('Enter some text here... '),
        ),
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );

    $form['buttons'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title_display' => 'invisible',
        '#attributes' => array(
            'style' => 'border: 0px; text-align: right',
            'class' => array('container-inline'),
        ),
    );

    $form['buttons']['copy'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' => 'Copy text',
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'copy_text',
            'wrapper' => 'out-text',
//          'method' => 'replace',
//          'effect' => 'fade',
        ),
    );

    $form['buttons']['reverse'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' => t('Reverse text'),
    );

    $form['buttons']['clear'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' => t('Clear text'),
    );

    $form['output'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#title' => t('Output text:'),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="out-text">',
        '#value' => '',
        '#attributes' => array(
            'placeholder' => t('Your text will appear here...'),
        ),
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );

    return $form;
    }
    print render(produce_form());

    function copy_text($form, &$form_state){
        $form['output']['#value'] = $form_state['values']['input'];
        return $return['output'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just two problem with your form:

1. Remove #value element from 'input' element
2. replace return $return['output']; with return $form['output'];

The problem with #value is that the element gets re-initialised on form render.

Here is the working version(copy button) of your code:

```
<?php


function playground_menu() {
  $items['playground/form'] = array(
    'title' => 'Form',
    'description' => '',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('playground_demo_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  return $items;
}

function playground_demo_form($form, $form_state) {

  $form['input'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Input text'),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="in-text">',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'placeholder' => t('Enter some text here... '),
    ),
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  $form['buttons'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'style' => 'border: 0px; text-align: right',
      'class' => array('container-inline'),
    ),
  );

  $form['buttons']['copy'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => 'Copy text',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'copy_text',
      'wrapper' => 'out-text',
//          'method' => 'replace',
//          'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
  );

  $form['buttons']['reverse'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => t('Reverse text'),
  );

  $form['buttons']['clear'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => t('Clear text'),
  );

  $form['output'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Output text:'),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="out-text">',
    '#value' => '',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'placeholder' => t('Your text will appear here...'),
    ),
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  return $form;
}

function copy_text($form, $form_state){
  $form['output']['#value'] = $form_state['values']['input'];
  return $form['output'];
}
```

Comment: Ok, so at first when I saw your point #2 I felt kind of stupid, it was always meant to be `return $form['output']` but at last, it made no difference. Furthermore the only thing removing the #value element did was generate an undefined index notice. Any other ideas? Thanks for your help so far

Comment: I just updated the code that's working in my D7 installation.

Comment: Hmmm, that's strange. I can see that the AJAX is now working as the 'Please wait' text is now appearing and it wasn't before, but the text is not being copied. The only thing I've changed is rather than using `playground_menu`, I've used `print render(drupal_get_form('playground_demo_form'));` as this is more suitable for my needs

Comment: In that case, try to use render(druapl_get_form("producer_form")); instead of render directly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. There is no `producer_form`?

Comment: i meant to say your form name.

Comment: that's what I tried in the first place because I copied your code directly so the form name is 'playground_demo_form' isn't it?

Comment: Yep, that should be fine. But calling it outside (i.e not inside any function) might be the problem as well.

Comment: I've just tried wrapping the lines in a function and calling the function and unfortunately it has made no difference. This seems really odd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16181/discussion-between-vijaycs85-and-andy).

Comment: Solved it! I was trying to create the form in a `Basic Page` node rather than a module which is why it wasn't working. As soon as I put your code in a module it worked. I don't know why this is or if there is a way around it, but I guess creating a module is more "in keeping" with the Drupal 7 system anyway and the propper way to do things